# Adding score when destroying a gameobject. (Unity + c#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to increase the score by one when i destroy a game object.
For this it's probably a very simple fix i imagine, but i just can't figure it out.

Here's the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Harvest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tree;
    private Spawner spawnerScript;
    public int treeScore;
    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        AddTreeScore();
        GameObject.Destroy(tree);
        spawnerScript.treeAmount--;
    }

    void AddTreeScore()
    {
        treeScore++;
        Debug.Log(treeScore);
    }
    void Start()
    {
        spawnerScript = FindObjectOfType<Spawner>();
    }



}
```

In the console it shows "1" when i destroy the tree(gameobject), but then it wont add to it anymore.
For now it's enough to display the socre in the console, "Debug.Log()" thing.

Also tried to write a separate script for it, but it didn't work at all.

Comment: trigger on `OnMouseUp` instead of `OnMouseDown`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have for example a Player in your scene (If not create a new empty GameObject) you could create a new script named score on your player (Or empty gameObject) and it could be like this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public static Score instance;

    private int score;
       

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
    }

    public void changeScore(int scoreChange)
    {
        score += scoreChange
    }

}
```

And in your Harvest script if you want to add +1 to the score, you can do it like this

```
Score.instance.changeScore(1);
```

If you want to remove 2 score you can do this

```
Score.instance.changeScore(-2);
```

Comment: Finally it's working, took a little bit of time to set up all the things, but now it works flawlessly. Thank you a LOT!

Answer (score 1):

The way you have this set up, every tree has its own treeScore that starts at 0 and is then increased by 1. A Way you can achieve what you need is to create a new GameObject in your scene and assign a Script with your score variable to it.
You will then need every tree to reference that GameObject:

```cs
GameObject scoreObject = GameObject.Find("Score Object's name");
```

and increase its score before being destroyed:

```cs
scoreObject.Score++;
Debug.Log(scoreObject.Score);
```